# Multi-dimensional array in Mongoose schema

Tags: node.js, mongoose, multidimensional-array

How can I define a multi-dimensional array in a Mongoose schema? I want to have a 2d array in my mongoose schema in order to locate a room in a hotel something like this.

```
var Room = new Schema({
   number: Number,
   type: String, // Room type id    
});

var Hotel = new Schema({
   ...
   rooms: [[Room]]    
});
```

Here's the error I get...

```
D:\projects\HotelBox\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\array.js:58
this.caster = new caster(null, castOptions);
              ^
TypeError: object is not a function
at new SchemaArray
```

I can fix it by defining `rooms` as `Schema.Types.Mixed` but then I can't validate room data at the time of creation.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, currently there is no such support in mongoose for multidimensional arrays utilisation.

That being said, and as you have been pointed, you can workaround this by using the `Schema.Types.Mixed` SchemaType, but then you will lose all the goodies that came to use native mongoose types.

However, you can overcome this by definining your own `validation`s by using [custom validators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html), as pointed at the official docs (they are very easy to use). The only caveat with custom validations is that they are triggered only when saving an instance.

If what you need is to trigger the validations and initilization time, you can use the more low-level [middleware hooks](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) which gives you fine grained control since you can invoke them at the following actions:

- `init`
- `validate`
- `save`
- `remove`

(note the `init` hook)

Hope this helps you to overcome your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can place coordinates of rooms in your model e.g.

```
var Room = new Schema({
    x: Number,
    y: Number,
    room_number: Number,
    room_type: String, // Room type id    
});

var Hotel = new Schema({
   ...
   rooms: [Room]    
});
```

Then create an array of all rooms:

```
var rooms = [];
var i = 0;
for (var y = 0; y<dim; y++) {
  for (var x = 0; x < dim; x++) {
    rooms[i] = new Room(x, y, ...);
  }
}
```

Then `insertMany` in mongoose.
And on client side you can iterate over all array by chunking it e.g.

```
var chunks = _.chunk(_.range(side*side), side)
for (var chunk in chunks) {
  for (var i in chunk) {
    console.log(rooms[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your schema definition must be (I also refactored your field names according to your schema. It can be dangerous to use reserved keyword like fields);

```
var Room = new Schema({
    room_number: Number
    room_type: String, // Room type id    
});

var Hotel = new Schema({
   ...
   rooms: [Room]    
});
```

Comment: This is a regular array. I need to make a 2d-array

Comment: Why do  you want to use 2d array? Your hotel schema will have several rooms. But you need to use subdocument. I didn't understand 2d

Comment: That's because I need to show the rooms in a 2d or maybe even 3d grid layout

Comment: But there is no such property in mongoose. You need to refactore your design

Comment: I know this is an old question.. However I'm facing the same issue.. The solution I'm planning to use is a slight modification to answer given by @HüseyinBABAL . Instead of `var Room = new Schema({})` I'm using
`var RoomRow = new Schema({ 
room : [{
  ...
  your room schema goes here
}]})`

This does not give any error. But I'm not sure if this is correct solution.. Can any one check and comment on the same ?

Comment: @pravin check out my answer